# Mail function is not working

Tags: email, joomla

I am facing a huge problem from tomorrow and I havent figured out still. I have done some programming work on a joomla site before a month. All was working fine, but from a week, the email functions have stopped working on the site. I have checked the following function in the test file, but I am not receiving the email.

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

$mailer->addRecipient("test@example.com");
$mailer->setSubject("test subject");

$mailer->setBody("email body");

$mailer->Send();
```

I am just stuck with the problem. I have emailed to the godaddy about this problem. They said that our servers are not affecting the emails sending process.
I would be very thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: have you changed any of the e-mailing settings in the Global Configuration?

Comment: Any error showing ? like SMTP error could not send email ?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
$send_status = JUtility::sendMail($from, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $bodyStr, true,'', null, null, $replyto, $replytoname);
```

Method 2

```
    $mail =& JFactory::getMailer();
    $mail->setSender(array($from, $fromname));
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setBody($bodyStr);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->addRecipient($recipient);
    $mail->Send();
```

Don't forget to replace the variables with your values. Plus Set the email setting at the backend - Global Configuration Tab -> Server

Comment: the problem is this that, the site is not sending emails at all. not registration nor virtuemart etc.